# How to find all the classes implementing a certain interface in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I know I can just put cursor on an Interface and "Find All References" for it.

But the result contains too much noise.

I only want to find all the classes implementing that interface. Not variable declaration with that interface.

And not by reflection. I want to finish this task within the IDE.

Any shortcut for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Resharper has this - "Find Implementers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"View Call Hierarchy"` by placing cursor on  member of the interface.

But if you want more you can `Resharper`

Comment: Re-Sharper is AWESOME!  "Go to implementation" rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find text ": INameofinterface" .

You can also use regexp to search for name of interface with ":" before it